# Is it possible to install Wubi using the ISO?

Tags: 11.10, wubi

I have the `Ubuntu 11.10` ISO downloaded but I want to install the `Wubi` for some specific reasons. When I do the click on the `Wubi` installer, it starts downloading files. Since I already have the ISO with me, is it possible to make use of this ISO during the installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Download or copy wubi.exe and put it in the same folder as the desktop iso. Run wubi.exe from there.

If needed,you can download wubi.exe from here : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

See [Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F)

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy.You just need to place the ISO  in the same folder as the Wubi exe file.

**Note** There should be no version mismatch

Answer (score 1):

You can also just drag the .iso files onto the wubi.exe icon and the installer come up. It will install with your existing .iso file. Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.